# Android, activity is not recreated on soft keyboard visibility change

Tags: android

When the software keyboard appears/disappears my activity is not restarted. Why is this? I have not done anything to handle these events myself, as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

I have not overridden onConfigurationChanged or declared android:configChanges in the activity entry in the manifest. I even tried setting android:configChanges="" in the manifest, but it does not help.

Edit: could it be my listview is catching the event, because I have enabled filtering?

Edit: disabling text filtering did not fix it.

Stack overflow is being a bitch and saying I don't have enough karma to answer, so i'll do it here:
The solution is to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29 as the activity is not supposed to restart.

Answer (score 1):

Soft keyboard changes do not trigger configuration change event. Only hardware keyboard does.